# Beamerposter does not automatically change font size of equation number

Tags: equations, labels, beamerposter

I'm using the beamerposter package.  While I'm able to change the font size of my equations, I cannot change the size of their corresponding labels.  Consider the code below as a MWE.  Is this possible to fix?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{beamerposter}

\setlength{\paperwidth}{11in}
\setlength{\paperheight}{8.5in}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tcolorbox}[width = 0.7\paperwidth]

\begin{tiny}
\begin{equation}
1+1=2
\end{equation}
\end{tiny}

\begin{equation}
1+1=2
\end{equation}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`beamerposter` contains a line

```
\renewcommand*{\normalfont}{\normalsize}
```

which is the cause of the problem.

Setting

```
\renewcommand*{\normalfont}{\relax}
```

locally solves the problem.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{beamerposter}

\setlength{\paperwidth}{11in}
\setlength{\paperheight}{8.5in}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tcolorbox}[width = 0.7\paperwidth]

{\renewcommand*{\normalfont}{\relax}
\tiny
\begin{equation}
1+1=2
\end{equation}
}

\begin{equation}
1+1=2
\end{equation}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you have many equations like that one and don't want to add that line each time, you can add the following lines in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\maketag@@@#1{\hbox{\m@th#1}}
\makeatother
```

so that the following MWE produces the same result as the above one:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{beamerposter}

\setlength{\paperwidth}{11in}
\setlength{\paperheight}{8.5in}

\makeatletter
\def\maketag@@@#1{\hbox{\m@th#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tcolorbox}[width = 0.7\paperwidth]

\begin{equation}
\tiny
1+1=2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
1+1=2
\end{equation}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```